# Check if ClassParent is of type X (not: equal type X)

Tags: delphi, oop

I am in a class function and want to find out if the parent class type is of the type TVMDNode .

"ClassParent is TVMDNode" does not work. (I do NOT want "ClassParent = TVMDNode").

How do I accomplish this task of doing a chain-check through the class hierarchy without requring the descendant classes to implement its own logic?

```
type
  TOID = string;
  TOIDPath = array of TOID;

class function TVMDNode.IsSupported(ANode: TOID): boolean; virtual;
begin
  result := true;
end;

class function TVMDNode.Supports(ANodePath: TOIDPath): boolean; // not virtual;
var
  n: integer;
begin
  // Check if the last segment is supported by our class
  n := Length(ANodePath);
  if not IsSupported(ANodePath[n-1]) then
  begin
    result := false; Exit;
  end;
  SetLength(ANodePath, n-1);

  // Recursively check if the previous segments are supported by the parent class, as long as they are of type TVMDNode (and therefore have the Supports() function)
  // This logic is implemented in the base class TVMDNode only and shall be applied to every descendant class without requiring override
  if ClassParent is TVMDNode then // <-- operator not applicable to this operand type
  begin
    if not (TVMDNode(ClassParent).Supports(ANodePath)) then
    begin
      result := false; Exit;
    end;
  end;

  result := true; Exit;
end;
```

The code should be compatible until Delphi 6.

Comment: A class parent is not something that changes all the time. Why would you want to check this anyway? When you write a class, you know what it inherits from, right?

Comment: I want to implement the logic FOR the descendants, so they don't have to implement the same logic again and again and again. Example: TB inherits from TA which inherits from TVMDNode. Calling TB.Supports() should go through TB.IsSupported(), TA.IsSupported() and finally TVMDNode.IsSupported(). The descendants of TVMDNode do only need to implement IsSupported().

Comment: The classparent is the class from which the class descends. There is not reason to check this, like I said before. But I think you are talking about the parent of the node (in a hierarchy), which is a completely different thing. Otherwise you question makes no sense to me.

Comment: I consider there should be 2 operators, "is" operator reffering if an object class IS EXACTLY the same class, and the "was" operator, if an object's class may be a NON-DIRECT DESCENDANT of another class

Comment: @umlcat What really matters is what operators there are in actuality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding Delphi's **is** operator.

It doesn't do what you think it does.
It does do what you want it to do.

Try the following:

```
LVar := TList.Create;
if LVar is TList then ShowMessage('Var is a TList');
if LVar is TObject then ShowMessage('Var is also a TObject');
```

However `ClassParent` returns a `TClass` and so you can't use **is**. However, you can use [`InheritsFrom`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.InheritsFrom). I.e.

```
if ClassParent.InheritsFrom(TVMDNode) then
```

---

Disclaimer: However, you might what to rethink your design. As a general rule you want to avoid all that typecasting. In OO each object has a particular type so that you know what you can do to it. Subclassing means you can do all the same things you could do to the ancestor. However overridden **virtual** methods may do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody has given the answer that I should use `InheritsFrom` which was the correct answer. The answer was deleted for some reason.

I had to do 2 corrections in the code:

1. Replacing `ClassParent is TVMDNode` with `ClassParent.InheritsFrom(TVMDNode)`
2. Change the typecast `TVMDNode(ClassParent)` to `TVMDNodeClass(ClassParent)` .

---

```
type
  TVMDNodeClass = class of TVMDNode;

if ClassParent.InheritsFrom(TVMDNode) then
begin
  if not (TVMDNodeClass(ClassParent).Supports(ANodePath)) then
  begin
    result := false; Exit;
  end;
end;
```

The following code will demonstrate that the chain checking in Support() does work as expected:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TVMDNode = class(TObject)
  public
    class procedure Supports;
  end;
  TVMDNodeClass = class of TVMDNode;
  TA = class(TVMDNode);
  TB = class(TA);

class procedure TVMDNode.Supports;
begin
  WriteLn('Do stuff in ' + Self.ClassName);

  if ClassParent.InheritsFrom(TVMDNode) then
  begin
    TVMDNodeClass(ClassParent).Supports;
  end;
end;

var
  b: TB; s: string;
begin
  b := TB.Create;
  b.Supports; // will output the correct chain TB -> TA -> TVMDNode
  Readln(s);
end.
```

Comment: That would be me. I deleted it and replaced it with another, because I thought I misunderstood your question. Anyway, glad it is solved. :)